# How can I create a CloudTableClient in .NET Core 2.2 app?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-table-storage, .net-core-2.2

This has been a mess for a big while with .NET Core 2!

I need A VERY simple thing - I need to use Table Storage in my **.NET Core 2.2** app using `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table` package. ok, let's do this, shall we?

First things first, let's create `CloudTableClient`:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common;

…

CloudTableClient tableClient = new CloudTableClient(
  new Uri("[WHAT TO PUT IN HERE in case of Azure and Emulator???]"),
  new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials() // => **THIS DOES NOT EVEN COMPILE! Auth is not a part of the package **
);
```

NICE! Where do we go from here?
Please don't point me to examples - they're not for .NET Core 2.2!

And let's not mix **Microsoft.Azure.Storage** and **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage** packages!

When is this going to be fixed? How to create CloudTableClient and use the CloudTable?

Comment: Is this a rant or a question?

Comment: The [documentation for StorageCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.auth.storagecredentials?view=azure-dotnet) seems to be pretty reasonable, for the second argument to the CloudTableClient constructor.

Comment: Have you tried mixing  Microsoft.Azure.Storage AND Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage packages in .NET Core 2.2???

Comment: Ah, so it's a different StorageCredentials class. Okay. If you could edit the question to make the different types clearer, along with what you've *tried* to construct a `StorageCredentials` object (and precisely which NuGet package you're using) you might find people are better able to help you. While I can understand wanting to let off steam, just ranting is not the best way of getting help.

Comment: (I don't think there even *is* a NuGet package called Microsoft.Azure.Storage, so it's not clear to me what you're using.)

Comment: You might need to downgrade to "9.0.0.1-preview of Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common" for now according to [Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.Protocol.IAuthenticationHandler' #519](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/519)

Comment: Yeah, the issue is from June 2018!

Comment: @alvipeo and hasn't been updated yet which means they haven't resolved it yet. What version of `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common` are you using?

Comment: Obviously the latest, the one that's on nuget.

Comment: @alvipeo the latest version *(at time of writing)* is [9.4.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common) in which case the solution is pretty obvious, downgrade to 9.0.0.1-preview of `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common` obviously.

Comment: @JonSkeet it's called [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common/9.4.2).

Comment: Also worth pointing out that [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table) is still in preview so expect it to be buggy and don't go using it in production projects. I'm afraid you'll just have to be patient, maybe go on [Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB .NET SDK github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2) open a new issue and rant about it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to conclude that there is no way of working with Azure Tables in .NET Core 2.x projects. Downgrading to some old packages or preview versions is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly fine:

```
var tableName = "TestTempTable";
var storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=....;AccountKey=....;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient(new TableClientConfiguration());
var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
```